# google email audit api

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-email-migration, google-email-audit-api

I am writing a program to download users mailbox from admin account.

For this I referred https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/

In the given code, an AuditService method is used as below:

```
AuditService service1 = new AuditService("*****", "*****", "*******", **"example.com-auditapp-v1"**);
    GenericEntry mailboxDumpEntry = service1.createMailboxDumpRequest(request);

    String requestId = ((MailBoxDumpRequest) mailboxDumpEntry).getRequestId();
    String status = mailboxDumpEntry.getStatus();
    String numberOfFiles = mailboxDumpEntry.getNumberOfFiles();
```

In this code, for AuditService method, I'm not getting from where to generate 4th parameter- the application id.

Also, I'm getting errors for `getRequestId()`, `getStatus()` and `getNumberOfFiles()` as method not found.

Can someone please help to sort out both queries.